# Add text to the end of multiple json files

Tags: python, json, metadata

I'm very new to programming so excuse any terrible explanations.  Basically I have 1000 json files all that need to have the same text added to the end.  Here is an example:

This is what it looks like now:

```
{"properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "image.png",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "category": "image",
    "creators": [
      {
        "address": "wallet address",
        "share": 100
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Which I want to look like this:

```
 {"properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "image.png",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "category": "image",
    "creators": [
      {
        "address": "wallet address",
        "share": 100
      }
    ]
  },
    "collection": {"name": "collection name"}
}
```

I've tried my best with append and update but it always tells me there is no attribute to append.  I also don't really know what I'm doing.

This will be embarrassing but here is what I tried and failed.

```py
import json

entry= {"collection": {"name": "collection name"}}

for i in range((5)):
  a_file = open("./testjsons/" + str(i) + ".json","r")
  json_obj = json.load(a_file)
  print(json_obj)

json_obj["properties"].append(entry)
a_file = open(str(i) + ".json","w")
json.dump(json_obj,a_file,indent=4)
a_file.close() 
json.dump(a_file, f)
```

Error code:  json_obj["properties"].append(entry)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: include the code you've tried and any errors

Comment: That's not a valid JSON file. There needs to be `{   }` around it.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `append`. Just `object['collection'] = {'name': collection_name}` where `object` is the object you got from `json.load`

Comment: I know, it's only part of the json file.

Comment: The way you've shown it, `collection` isn't inside the `properties` object.

Comment: Is it supposed to be inside `properties`, or where you show it in your example result?

Comment: It is not supposed to be inside properties, where I show on the example result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't use `append()` to add to a dictionary. You can either assign to the key to add a single entry, or use `.update()` to merge dictionaries.

```
import json

entry= {"collection": {"name": "collection name"}}

for i in range((5)):
    with open("./testjsons/" + str(i) + ".json","r") as a_file:
        a_file = open("./testjsons/" + str(i) + ".json","r")
        json_obj = json.load(a_file)
        print(json_obj)
        
    json_obj.update(entry)
    with open(str(i) + ".json","w") as a_file:
        json.dump(json_obj,a_file,indent=4)
```

Comment: This is close.  I need it outside of "properties", so assign to the key?

Comment: I updated the answer to update the main object instead of `properties`.

Answer (score 0):

JSON, like XML, is a specialized data format. You should always *parse* the data and work with it as JSON where possible. This is different from a plain text file where you would 'add to the end' or 'append' text.

There are a number of json parsing libraries in Python, but you'll probably want to use the [`json` encoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) that is built in to the standard Python library. For a file, `myfile.json`, you can:

```
import json
with open('myfile.json`, 'r') as f:
    myfile = json.load(f) # read the file into a Python dict
    myfile["collection"] = {"name": "collection name"} # here you're adding the "collection" field to the end of the Python dict
# If you want to add "collection" inside "properties", you'd do something like
#.  myfile["properties"]["collection"] = {"name": "collection name"}

with open('myfile.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(myfile, f) # save the modified dict into the json file
```